# How can I apply a taphold event to every button in a listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, jquery-mobile-listview

I am trying to detect the jQuery mobile taphold event on a list that gets created dynamically. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div>
<ul id="resultsListView" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: results">
      <li><div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="goButton" data-bind="click: $parent.clickToGo">Accept</a></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="stopButton" data-bind="click: $parent.clickToStop">Deny</a></div>
      </div></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
$( "#goButton" ).on( "taphold", self.tapholdHandler );
$( "#stopButton" ).on( "taphold", self.tapholdHandler );

this.tapholdHandler =  function( event ){
   alert("Tap hold works");
}
```

But this approach only works for the first entry in the list, none of the other entries seem to be attached to the taphold event, can anyone help with the mistake in my approach?

Comment: For dynamically created element `$("static parent").on("taphold", "dynamic elm", function`

Comment: Thanks Omar, I am pretty new to Javascript and Jquery mobile and I'm not sure I follow your advice, could you give me a sample piece of code in the context of my code in my question? What would my static parent be? Do you need to see more of my HTML code?

Comment: Can you post a simple code of how you add items? A jsfiddle would be of help.

Comment: Actually I got it working, thanks, if you want to post it as the answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Static patent is `ul` in case it isn't created dynamically. Or just `$(document).on(.....` is enough. But the first is faster. I'm glad it worked for you.